# Cluster very many sparse binary vectors

Tags: clustering, bigdata, binary

I have a very big set of high-dimensional, but sparse binary vectors. Each vector represents a "one-hot-style" n-gram sequence of words where each index of the words that occur in the n-gram is set to 1, all others to 0. E.g.

```
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,...]
```

An efficient representation for a 5-gram:

```
[5,10,235,1253,5521]
```

What I would like to do is generate such n-gram representations from a large text corpus. Hence, this may easily result in a vocabulary size of hundreds of thousands (depending on potential pre-processing steps including stopword removal, stemming, etc.) and even more distinct n-grams (`m`).
This could be represented as a matrix of size `m x vocab_size`.

Subsequently, I would like to reduce the number of rows by clustering similar n-grams together while retaining the contained words. For instance:

```
[5,7,10,12,15],[5,8,10,15,18] -> [5,7,8,10,12,15,18]
```

My naive approach would be to apply some traditional clustering algorithm in order to assign each entry in the initial n-gram set to a specific cluster and then perform a union over all the n-grams assigned to a cluster.

1st question: what would be an sensible algorithm for clustering sparse binary representations?
2nd question: how could this be done with a very big data set?

Comment: Machine learning on text data is not my area, but the data encoding you describe does not seem the most natural: you encode each n-gram as a sparse vector where each index represents a different word, rather than (what I would try first) encoding each *document* as a sparse vector, where each index represents a different n-gram. Whatever clustering or duplicate detection algorithm you use should result in merging subsequent n-grams, thus indirectly you go back to the alternative (traditional?) document-by-ngram representation.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think clustering is the right approach here. You want to merge them automatically, but clustering is too unpredictable for this; you need to manually examine clustering results.

I suggest you look at **near duplicate detection** instead. You want to merge documents that have a high overlap. There are some interesting - and scalable - algorithma for that. In particular, minhash (and later work) is worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

A few points.  First, if you're doing text analytics, there are methods to reduce the space, e.g. stop word filtering and word stemming.  You can also consider training a word2vec model, such as that provided by gensim: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html

The particular strength of this method will be to take the space from O(10^7) to O(10^2) (but the vectors will become dense).  From there, you can either try approximate nearest neighbor, or cosine similarity.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but your points do not really address my specific questions. I had even explicitly mentioned stop word removal and stemming in the question. Also, I know word2vec, but I am following a different trail here.